# Condition with counter in timer

Tags: javascript

So I have been trying to make like a timer type thing to count from 0 to 5 (one number up every sec, like normal timer) then stopping at 5 but It's not stopping at 5. What did I do wrong?

```js
var licz = 0;

function timer() {
  window.setInterval(
    function() {
      document.getElementById('timer_r').innerHTML = licz;
      licz++;
      if (licz >= 5) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }
    , 1000
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="timer" on value="timer" onclick="timer();">
<p>Odliczanie: <span id='timer_r'> _ </span></p>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need to be doing is complete your conditional like:-

```html
        <script>

    var licz = 0;
    function timer() {
    window.setInterval(
        function(){
            document.getElementById('timer_r').innerHTML = licz;
    
    if (licz < 5) {
        licz++;
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    }

   
}, 1000);  
}

</script>
<br>    
<input type = "button" id = "timer" on value = "timer" onclick="timer();">
<p>Odliczanie: <span id = 'timer_r'> _ </span></p>
```

Comment: This will not cancel the `setInterval`.

Comment: @BenAston you're right

Answer (score 2):

Declare "timer" as a variable, like so:

```
let timer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('timer_r').innerHTML = licz;
  licz++;
 }, 1000
)
if (licz >= 5) {
 clearInterval(timer)
}
```

This is because when you declare timer as a function, it is a separate function rather than an interval. You would have to call timer and create a loop, instead of just a normal interval.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` returns an integer ID corresponding to the timer.

This id can be supplied to `clearInterval` to stop the timer.

In your code you are supplying the function `timer` to `clearInterval`, meaning the timer is never cancelled.

```js
let licz = 0, intervalId = null;

function timer() {
  intervalId = window.setInterval(
    function() {
      document.getElementById('timer_r').innerHTML = licz;
      licz++;
      if (licz > 5) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }
    , 1000
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="timer" on value="timer" onclick="timer();">
<p>Odliczanie: <span id='timer_r'> _ </span></p>
```